# Count ways to reduce nim piles to get XOR sum 0

Tags: algorithm, math, dynamic-programming, counting

**Given**: A set of `n` piles of coins (`n <= 100`), such that their XOR-sum (nim-sum) is *not* 0. Each pile can contains coins which can be represented by 30 bits.
**Desired**: To get an overall XOR (nim sum) of 0.
**Restriction**: Stones can be removed from any of the piles, as long as atleast one pile is left unchanged. Stones cannot be added to any pile.
**Required Output**: The number of ways in which this can be achieved, modulo a large prime.

I understand that leaving one pile unchanged means that the XOR of the remaining piles must be equal to the coins in the unchanged pile. I was trying to use Dynamic Programming, but got nowhere with it. One tricky aspect seems to be that any partial solution with some pile unchanged may be counted more than once when considering some other pile that had also remained unchanged. This *was* a contest question, and the contest is over now. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is that homework or a competition (which one)?

Comment: It is a competition on interviewstreet, but I am pretty much out of it. I was looking for hints/direction to work on. I'll edit the question. Or delete and post later?

Comment: @MLR: And what's the prize for us?

Comment: @MLR: If it's a competition, isn't it slightly unfair to ask for a community's help? :)

Comment: @AndyProwl I suppose it is. The competition is over now though.

Comment: @G.Bach Sorry, nim-sum is simply the XOR of the numbers.